# Non-substantial remote door locking options for indoor rooms?

Tags: doors, lock, home-automation

I need to be able to secure a couple indoor rooms with wireless locks. These don't need to be substantial locks since they're just inside a house, but unfortunately I'm not seeing any real wireless locking door options. Does such a contraption even exist?

Use cases could be to have a wireless button, similar to these devices (I suppose a phone could work, but that's not very convenient since these are localized and it would be better to just be able to press a handy button):
[image: wireless device]

that would then trigger the door lock mechanism from 10-100 feet away.

I'm not talking about *really* keeping someone out, just deterrents for bedrooms, office, bathroom, etc. where you want to say "hey, don't come in here while I'm busy, etc."

Comment: If this isn't supposed to be a real deterrent, does it even need to be a lock? Rigging up a remote-controlled flag or screen shouldn't be that hard, without worrying about hooking into a lock. Minimum there would be to get a remote-controlled battery-operated light, and a sign that says "Do not disturb light".

Comment: That's an interesting idea and it has crossed my mind. I'm not 100% sure, but I'm open to considering this option further and discussing with the other party who this is really for primarily.

Answer (score 1):

If you do find a solution that works for you make 100% sure that it is possible to enter or leave the rooms even when they are locked. In the case of fire or other emergency situation the last thing you need is inability to escape or enter the room to save someone. You need to consider that the power in such situation may be off, rescue personnel will not be familiar with whatever gadgets you have rigged up and in the frenzy of the situation trying to locate remote controls may not be feasible.

It will always be best if such access capability is entirely mechanical and localized right at each door unit. No dependency on power, remote tools or non-standard operation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Knob via Wayfair]

[image: Knob via Home Depot]

[image: Deadbolt via Home Depot]

Some different options that I saw while perusing some different sites.

Comment: These are really nice options. Might need to go down this path.  Wonder if there are ways to get a couple remotes per door?